# Meshed Tree and horizontal orientation

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to implement a tree like shown in the pictucre in tikz:
[image]

I found the forrest package, but wasn't able to achieve neither the 'half-horizontal' shape nor the 'meshed' shape yet. I would appreciate some help here.

Right now, this is the closest I get (inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160280/horizontal-probability-tree-with-tikz)):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{nicelabel/.style={midway, font=\scriptsize}}

\begin{forest}
[ \phantom{A},for tree={calign=last, grow=0}
[B, edge label={node[nicelabel, below]{$\frac{4}{9}$}} 
    [C, edge label={node[nicelabel,below]{$\frac{2}{7}$}} 
        [\phantom{D}, no edge] [A, edge label={node[nicelabel,above]{$\frac{5}{5}$}}]] 
        [E, edge label={node[nicelabel,above]{$\frac{5}{6}$}}
                        [F]
                        [G]]]
[H, edge label={node[nicelabel,above]{$\frac{5}{9}$}}
    [I]
    [J
    [K]
    [L]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I would need to merge the nodes I-E K-G and F-A but have no clue how.

Comment: You must use the `matrix` library of `tikz`.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? MWE? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The matrix libary seems much better for what I plan to do. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a fan of `forest` but I don't think it is the best tool for this job. It doesn't naturally lend itself to nodes with multiple parents, for example. I'm glad somebody suggested a matrix and that that looks better for what you are trying to do ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution uses of `matrix of nodes`. `data` and `line` styles are defined for solid circles and connection lines respectively.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,shapes,automata,positioning,calc}
\tikzset{
    data/.style={
        circle,
        fill=black,outer sep=5pt,
        inner sep=1pt
    },
line/.style = {draw, -},
} 

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1 and 1,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]

 \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=0.5cm,nodes={anchor=center}]{
   &A & {B} &C&   D\\
 1 &\node [data] (a1){}; & \node [data] (b1){}; & \node [data](c1){};& \node [data] (d1){}; \\
 2 & & \node [data] (b2) {}; & \node [data](c2) {};&\node [data](d2){}; \\
 3 & & & \node [data] (c3) {};&   \node [data] (d3)   {}; \\
 4 & & & &   \node [data] (d4)   {}; \\
 };
%  --- Draw edges
\foreach \i in {1}
\foreach \j in {1,2}{
 \draw[line] (a\i)  -- (b\j);
 \draw[line] (b\i)  -- (c\j);
 \draw[line] (c\i)  -- (d\j);
 }
\foreach \i in {2}
\foreach \j in {2,3}{
 \draw[line] (b\i)  --  (c\j);
 \draw[line] (c\i)  --  (d\j);
 }
\foreach \i in {3}
\foreach \j in {3,4}{
 \draw[line] (c\i)  --  (d\j);
 }
% --- adding labels
\path (a1)--node[above]{\tiny a}(b1) --node[above]{\tiny b}(c1) --node[above]{\tiny c} (d1);
\path (b2)--node[above]{\tiny g}(c2) --node[above]{\tiny h}(d2);
\path (a1)--node[right]{\tiny d}(b2); 
\path (b1)--node[right]{\tiny e}(c2);
\path (c1)--node[right]{\tiny f}(d2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was able to achieve a satisfying solution with the matrix library but this one is great. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As was already commented, `forest` could not be the best solution for this kind of diagrams and I also prefer to use `matrix`. But it's still possible to draw it as a *regular* tree (with `forest`) and add some extra edges:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{nicelabel/.style={midway, font=\scriptsize}}

\begin{forest}
[,name=0,for tree={calign=last, grow=0, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt,outer sep=2pt }
    [, edge label={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize]{d}}, name=d
            [,name=i 
                [,name=j ]
                [ ]] 
            [, edge label={node[pos=.25,above=-2pt,font=\scriptsize]{g}},name=g
                        [, edge label={node[pos=.25,above=-2pt,font=\scriptsize]{h}},name=h]]]
    [, edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize]{a}}, name=a
            [, edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize]{b}}, name=b
            [, edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize]{c}}, name =c]]]
    ]
    \draw (a)--(g) node[above right=-3pt,midway,font=\scriptsize]{e} (b)--(h) node[above right=-3pt,midway,font=\scriptsize]{f};
    \begin{scope}[font=\small]
    \node[above=5mm of 0] (A) {A};
    \node at (A-|a) {B};
    \node at (A-|b) {C};
    \node at (A-|c) {D};
    \node[left=5mm of 0] (1) {1};
    \node at (d-|1) {2};
    \node at (i-|1) {3};
    \node at (j-|1) {4};
    \end{scope}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]